# Docker volumes_from does not work as expected

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Hello Guys I am facing a problem in volumes_from in docker-compose file.
- i have 3 services first one has my app files and the second is php-fpm which take volume from the data service.
my file is like this.

```
version: '2'

services:
  cms_data:
    image: ""image from private repository contain application file"
    container_name: "cms-data"

  php-fpm:
    image: "image from private repository contain php configuration"
    container_name: "php-fpm"
    env_file:
      - ../.env.production
    volumes_from:
      - cms_data
    working_dir: /iprice/octobercms
    expose:
      - 9000
    depends_on:
      - cms_data
    restart: "always"

  nginx:
    image: "image from private repository contain nginx configuration"
    container_name: "nginx"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - php-fpm
    volumes_from:
      - cms_data
    depends_on:
      - cms_data
    restart: "always"
```

the cms-data image has the files which is correct.
but the php-fpm container doesn't please help.

Comment: How do you determine that it does not have the files? Did you try to exec into the running container and check?

Comment: yes, i did.
i have run this command to check the data image
```docker run -it my-image sh```

Comment: and also this command to check the running container ```docker exec -it php-fpm bash```

Answer (score 0):

`volumes_from` mounts the volumes present on other containers. It does not create new volumes.

The `cms-data` container does not have any volumes associated with it. So `volumes_from` cant do anything. If you want to share a particular folder inside `cms-data`, first create a volume linking that folder.

**NOTE**: creating a volume will overwrite the contents of the internal container with the `/path/on/host` folder. So first copy the contents of the container folder to this host folder.

1. Run the current docker-compose as is so the containers start.
2. Copy the contents from the `cms-data` container to the host folder:

   docker cp :/path/to/shared/folder /path/on/host
3. Make the following changes to the docker-compose file and restart.

   ```
   services:
     cms_data:
       image: ""image from private repository contain application file"
       container_name: "cms-data"
       volumes:
         - /path/on/host:/path/to/shared/folder

       ...
   ```

Comment: Hello Manish, thanks for your answer. but as i mentioned this is pre build image it has all the volumes. and i do not think we need to put the application files to the host.

Comment: i just put the yml file on the host and once i build it, it will pull the images from the ECR

Comment: after starting the containers, what is the output of `docker volume ls`.? Is it different from before starting the containers?

Comment: it's not different

Comment: yeah. Images don't have volumes inside them. Volumes can only be defined at run-time. So if you want to share the folder as a volume, you have to create it.

Comment: so I should create a volume in this yml file? could you share an example please.

Comment: See my answer :)

Comment: there is no files in the host all the files in the image itself.

Comment: Yes. That is the problem. If you create a volume now, whatever is on your host folder will get overwritten with the internal container folder (if host folder is empty then internal also becomes empty). I assume you have some files _inside_ the container that you want to share with the other containers as volumes, right? To do this, first you should copy those files to some host folder, then mount this host folder back to the container.

Comment: Is there is any way that we can share the volumes without touching the host?